# How to install two java version running for different directory in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run two application at same time with different java version. so How can I set JAVA_HOME in path different for different directories.

Comment: Write a wrapper script for launching each application, and set the relevant environment variables in the scripts.

Comment: any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Run your application via script like this:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45'
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

java -jar your_jar.ar
```